# can't consume Post method in angular 7

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

i've been working on an Angular project. where i should fetch data from server via web service (ASP.NET web api core).so GET method works perfectly but i can't consume Post Method. i get this error 
[image]

my Post Method

```
        [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostMerchandiser([FromBody] Presentent presentent)
    {
        using (var db = new DMerchContext(ClientConnectionString))
        {
            presentent.idElement = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            presentent.etat = 0;
            db.Add(presentent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

also i added this to my web.config

```
<customHeaders>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, 
   Authorization" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" 
  value="POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />      
</customHeaders>
```

Angular code (Service)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Configuration } from '../Services/Configuration';
import { Merchandiser } from 'src/Models/Merchandiser';

@Injectable()
 export class MerchandiserService {
   private actionUrl: string;

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public configuration: Configuration) 
{
    this.actionUrl = configuration.serverWithApiUrl;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////// Login Services 
 /////////////////////////////////////////
public getMerchandisers<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.actionUrl + 
 'Presentents/GetPresentents');
}

public PostMerchandiser<T>(merchandiser: Merchandiser): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.actionUrl+'Presentents/PostMerchandiser', 
merchandiser);
}
}
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Where is your Angular code?

Comment: You have to enable / set up CORS middleware on the server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2 (if think web.config is just for IIS)

Comment: @ChristianBenseler check it now

Comment: @WilliamLohan thank you so much it worked, finally

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable/set up CORS middleware on the server. I think `web.config` is just for IIS.

You can accomplish this for aspnetcore by following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

note: copied from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873089/cant-consume-post-method-in-angular-7?noredirect=1#comment96516236_54873089) so people can see solution

Comment: This is a link only answer -- please provide more details on how to answer the question

Comment: @AK47 this was the solution that worked for the OP. I don't know how to go into more detail other than rewriting the Microsoft documentation for setting up the CORS middleware here in SO

Comment: The awnser IS "You have to enable / set up CORS middleware on the server" the link is just extra information on how to do that with the specific server frame work. This is not a link only answer.